# Facebook Like button in IE7 issue

Tags: facebook, dotnetnuke, facebook-like

I am having an issue with the Facebok Like button image in IE7 ONLY. Here is the code i am using to implement this:

```
<html xmlns:og="http://opengraphprotocol.org/schema/" xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
.
.
.
<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1"></script>
<fb:like href="http://www.facebook.com/xxxxx" show_faces="false" width="100" colorscheme="dark" style="float:left;"></fb:like>
.
.
.
```

The issue I am seeing is only in IE7. The like button looks great. Once you "like" the item it also looks great. After un-liking you get this: http://screencast.com/t/6qno8HDvYh

If you "like" it again, you get this: http://screencast.com/t/NlkXbaD5

Any help is appreciated. I have looked all over Google for anyone else having this issue. Here is the site for reference:http://auto-owners.com/  Any help is appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried the IFrame version of the facebook like? We've switched to the IFrame version for DNN -- it has caused us the fewest issues.

```
<iframe src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href&amp;send=true&amp;layout=standard&amp;width=450&amp;show_faces=false&amp;action=like&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;font&amp;height=35" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:450px; height:35px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>
```

Generated here:

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/

You also have the nice benefit of not having your page load choke when Facebook servers go down (happened last month to a lot of sites that used the script version)

Comment: Hi @hamlin11, I will give this a try. I have found out something else... It shows up for me consistently in IE8 with IE7 Browser and Document Mode enabled, and only when I am LOGGED IN to Facebook. I will try switching it to the iframe like you suggested and let you know how it goes. It would be disappointing if this is the answer however, because i took so much time getting this site all set up with FBML!

Comment: Agreed, it can be frustrating. I don't remember the specific reason why we switched to the iFrame version -- I was resistant, but it was necessary for us.

Comment: Hi @hamlin11, I placed in the iframe code and I am STILL seeing the issue: http://screencast.com/t/TvY9RCeAdKBE. It's so odd because I see this on ANY page in IE7. Here is a screen shot of Facebook's like button page in IE7... http://screencast.com/t/9CVmh48SY2. Looks like it is only doing it when the width is set to 283 pixels or less... It doesn't give a minimum width for the button as a whole.

Comment: I have found a thread on the Facebook developers forum and posted my findings there: http://forum.developers.facebook.net/viewtopic.php?pid=340118#p340118

Comment: Interesting -- at least it's not specific to your software. Make sure and post an answer here if you find it (Yes, you can accept your own answers on Stackoverflow :) )

Answer (score 2):

If you use the iFrame version on IE7 check that it isn't causing the resources on your page to load multiple times which, in our case, occasionally caused an uninformative JavaScript error to display. You can use IE Development Helper add-on to view the HTTP request stack.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:-

```
<div style="width:48px; overflow:hidden!important;">
 <fb:like class='fb_like' href="http://www.correcturlhere.tld" send="false"
   width="320" height="24" colorscheme="dark" font="tahoma">
 </fb:like>
</div>
```

The width="320" fixes the IE7 issue while the div overflow property prevents unwanted FB stuff displaying. The IE7 problem seems to occur therefore when the width atttribute of the FB code is less than the minimum width for the standard layout (225px).

You may want to enclose the opening and closing div tags in IE-specific conditionals:-

```
<!--[if IE 7]><div><![endif]-->
[FB code here]
<!--[if IE 7]><div><![endif]-->
```

Fixed it for me. Hope this helps.